# ORA-04091: table JOSEP.EMP is mutating, trigger/function may not see it

Tags: oracle, plsql

> "ORA-04091: table JOSEP.EMP is mutating, trigger/function may not see it"

I have to show a message with the old and the new salary, and the code of the employed (emp_no) in it, and I'm not able to do it.

```
create or replace trigger emp_AU 
after update of salario 
on emp for each row
    declare
    v_emp_no emp.emp_no%type;  
    begin
    select emp_no into v_emp_no FROM emp;
    insert into auditaemple VALUES ((select count(*) from auditaemple)+1, 'El salario del empleado '||v_emp_no||'antes era de '||:old.salario||' y ahora será '||:new.salario, sysdate);
    end emp_AU;
```

Doing it like this gives the "ORA-04091:" error. If I eliminate v_emp_no, I won't get the message, but I need to show the code of the employed. What I'm I doing wrong.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Use `:new.emp_no`. Besides: using `max()+1` to generate an ID is **really** bad idea.

Comment: For awoiding mutation on oracle you can use compound trigger, but here you dont need to do that. Just remove select on emp and use :new like in previous comment. For primary key incrementing columns use sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Reason which caused the mutating table error is in selecting data from the table when it is *in the middle of a transaction* - you're updating it, and - at the same time - selecting from it. As you can't do that (well, you *could*, there are workarounds, but you shouldn't), Oracle won't let you.

There's no need to select `emp_no`; you already have it - reference it with `:new` pseudorecord. Besides, the way you put it, you'd get `TOO-MANY-ROWS` error as there's no `WHERE` clause which would restrict resultset to a single row.

Don't use `count + 1` (nor `max + 1` or similar "technique"), especially if you're about to populate a column which is supposed to be unique. As long as it'll work in a single-user environment, it'll fail (sooner or later) in a multi-user one. Use a sequence (or, if your database supports it, an identity column).

Here's a working example of how you might have done that.

First, test case:

```
SQL> create table temp as select empno emp_no, sal salario
  2                       from emp where deptno = 10;

Table created.

SQL> create table auditaemple (id number, text varchar2(100), datum date);

Table created.

SQL> create sequence seqa;

Sequence created.
```

Trigger:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_bu_emp
  2    before update of salario on temp
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    insert into auditaemple (id, text, datum)
  6      values (seqa.nextval,
  7              'El salario del empleado '||:new.emp_no||' antes era de '||
  8               :old.salario||' y ahora será '||:new.salario, sysdate);
  9  end;
 10  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select * from temp;

    EMP_NO    SALARIO
---------- ----------
      7782       2450
      7839       5000
      7934       1300

SQL> update temp set salario = 9000 where emp_no = 7839;

1 row updated.

SQL> select * From auditaemple;

        ID TEXT                                     DATUM
---------- ---------------------------------------- ----------------
         1 El salario del empleado 7839 antes era d 11.04.2019 21:47
           e 5000 y ahora será 9000


SQL>
```